# CodeKit compilation error including JS file in coffee file

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm just getting started with CodeKit and it's awesome so far, but I'm having trouble including a JavaScript file in a CoffeeScript file.

In the CoffeeScript file I have the line:

```
# @codekit-prepend './vendor/backbone.js'
```

which results in the following error:

```
SyntaxError: In /var/folders/t1/h24_m5yx2yq5sjc2jztvh2xr0000gn/T/CodeKitTempFolder.rrBQ5JI7WP7b1dQ/temp.coffee, reserved word "function" on line 27
at SyntaxError (unknown source)
at Lexer.exports.Lexer.Lexer.error (/Users/makala/Downloads/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/coffee/lib/coffee-script/lexer.js:682:13)
at Lexer.exports.Lexer.Lexer.identifierToken (/Users/makala/Downloads/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/coffee/lib/coffee-script/lexer.js:86:16)
at Lexer.exports.Lexer.Lexer.tokenize (/Users/makala/Downloads/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/coffee/lib/coffee-script/lexer.js:33:19)
at Object.exports.compile.compile (/Users/makala/Downloads/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/coffee/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:47:32)
at compileScript (/Users/makala/Downloads/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/coffee/lib/coffee-script/command.js:182:33)
at fs.stat.notSources.(anonymous function) (/Users/makala/Downloads/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/coffee/lib/coffee-script/command.js:152:18)
at fs.readFile (fs.js:176:14)
at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
```

The CoffeeScript file compiles perfectly without that line.

The JS file I am attempting to prepend is *not* compiled directly and is "concatenated + minified". The CS file is *not* being checked by JSHint/Lint, and it *is* being minified.

I am thinking this error could be due to lack of error suppression (see "JavaScript and CoffeeScript Imports" > "Suppressing Errors" at http://incident57.com/codekit/help.php). But the "show errors" checkbox is not visible in the CodeKit application.

Oh, and one more thing, the outputted javascript file contains the original coffeescript. I'm not sure if this is a cause or a result of the failed compilation.

Any ideas of what could be causing the compilation to fail?

Thanks for looking :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For technical reasons (variable/function shadowing, etc), it's not possible to combine CS and JS files directly. What you'd need to do is create a NEW Javascript file that imports (using the prepend/append statements) the OUTPUT file that is generated when your CS file is compiled and the JS file you want to import.
>
> Then, whenever you save your Coffee file, CodeKit will do the right thing and recompile the javascript file. Cheers!

*Source*: Bryan Jones, CodeKit author